# implicitely set an associated type

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'm trying to figure out how to implicitely set a Generic (type of a argument) in a class without changing the type of the whole class to something like SomeTestClass< SomeType>, where the owner of an object has to know the type of the generic.

**Example**

This example DOESNT work! This is how I would like it to work

```
protocol SomeTestProtocol {
    associatedtype T

    init(arg: T)
}
```

Don't want to use SomeTestClass< T>
because the class, which holds this class
wont know the type of the generics used

```
class SomeTestClass: SomeTestProtocol {
    required init(arg: T) {
    }

    // Use T outside the init-scope
}
```

Note: The Protocol is just a try for a work-around! It isn't necessary for the final solution

So **the main question** is: How can I use T outside the init-scope in the class below without using a class-generic, which must be known when owning an object

```
class SomeTestClass2/*< T>*/ {
    init(arg: T) {
    }

    // Use T outside the init-scope
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "How can I use T outside the init-scope in the class below without using a class-generic, which must be known when owning an object" Unclear what those words can mean. The placeholder type for a generic must _always_ be resolved _at compile time_. Of _course_ the type is known. That is what a generic _is_. It is not blank slate. It is merely a placeholder expression used in a shorthand saying that two types are some same type.

Comment: Continuing matt's point here: Both generics and PATs (protocols w/ associated types) include type parameters. The difference between them is that in a generic, the creator of the instance decided the type values, and in a PAT, the creator of the implementation decides the type values. Someone *must* decide the type values. Who you want to make the decision is how you decide whether to use a generic or a protocol. (90% of the time in Swift, the answer is a generic.)

Answer (score 0):

Important note, the `T` from `associatedtype T` and the `T` from `init<T>` can be different types. They are both defining a generic type with different scopes an could be different. If you want them to be the same, the init should be

```
init(arg: T)
```

---

If `SomeTestClass` is always going to use the same type, you can add

```
typealias T = Int // or something
```

or implement the init as

```
required init(arg: Int)
```

It works if you get rid of the `associatedtype T` from the protocol. Though this removes `SomeTestClass.T` form existence.

Comment: I dont want to Hardcode the type in the class itself. It should be set in the init-Method of the class by a parameter. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare an associated type in a protocol, that type will become generic over different implementations of the protocol, but each conforming class will need to assign a concrete type to that associate type as a `typealias` (which can be done implicitly by declaring all variables/functions using the associated type with the same concrete type), so your conforming types won't be generic.

If you want to have generic methods in your conforming classes, you'll need to make the classes themselves generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want access to `T` outside of `init`, then you just store `T` in a property:

```
class S {
    let theType: Any.Type
    init<T>(arg: T) {
        theType = T.self
    }
}
```

I suspect you actually want something different than what you've said you want. I suspect you want to store `arg`. But if so, what do you plan to *do* with `arg` if you have no idea what its type is? What methods can you call? What function could it be the return value of? Without resorting to `as?`, there's nothing you can do with `T` (and reliance on `as?` generally means you've misunderstood your types).

So you need to start with how you want `T` and `SomeTestClass` to be used. Without that, it's impossible to discuss how `T` should be stored (the storage is irrelevant if you never use it).